# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' error

Tags: python, numpy

Hello Guys I am new to Machine and Trying to learn it from you-tube but when i run their code on my computer i got this error Please help....!!!!

Code:

```
import random

random.shuffle(training_data)

for sample in training_data:
    print(sample[1])

X = []
y = [] 

y = np.array(y)

for features  , label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X  = np.array(X).reshape(-1 , IMG_SIZE , IMG_SIZE,1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVQsQ.png)

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `y = np.array(y)` to do?

Comment: The error is exactly what it says: you can't append to a numpy array. You can append to a list `[]` which is what  `y` is before you converted. `X` is also a list, which is why you don't get an error trying to append to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your y to numpy to after loop. As @Tyberius mentioned in the comments, you cannot append to numpy array. Therefore, you need to keep `y` as list in your for loop and then convert it after appending. Like here:

```
import random

random.shuffle(training_data)

for sample in training_data:
    print(sample[1])

X = []
y = [] 

for features  , label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

y = np.array(y)

X  = np.array(X).reshape(-1 , IMG_SIZE , IMG_SIZE,1)
```